# How to include the slash at the end of base_url Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

So I have a dynamic link and I wanted to write the dynamic link like this:

```
echo "<a href='".base_url('browse/category/').$all_categories[$j]['id']."'>";
```

However the link appears to be like this...

```
www.example.com/browse/category2
```

There is no slash between the category and the dynamic number (2). So i figured another way but i think it is a messy way like this:

```
base_url('browse/category')."/".$all_categories[$j]['id']
```

Is there a better way to do this??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo base_url('browse/category/'.$all_categories[$j]['id']);
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/browse/category/2
```

Comment: Alright, that works and looks much neater. thanks for the help!

Comment: echo "<a href='".base_url('browse/category/'.$all_categories[$j]['id'])."'>";

Comment: I am waiting 2 more minutes

Answer (score 0):

echo base_url().'browse/category/'.$all_categories[$j]['id']);

This is another way